# Replace newline character in JSON NSString

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring

I am banging my head against a wall and decided to check in with you guys.

I have the following JSON Data as a NSString:

```
{
    "PATIENTID": "51853",
    "MSWREFERRAL": " ",
    "TIMEIN": " ",
    "PRECAUTIONOTHERNOTE1": " ",
    "AGE": "70",
    "SAFETY2": " ",
    "VISITTYPE": " ",
    "RAMP": " ",
    "BANNISTER": " ",
    "CREATETIMESTAMP": "1308519326",
    "SAFETY1": " ",
    "AGENCYNAME": "RESPONSE HOME CARE",
    "STAIRS": " ",
    "AGENCYID": "415",
    "GUID": "845A481E-8F54-4737-9F55-05FD10E3B931",
    "ASSIST": " ",
    "EVALDATE": "06/19/2011",
    "PULMONARY": "NO",
    "DOB": "01/17/1941",
    "GENDER": " ",
    "STATUS": "pending",
    "SETTING": " ",
    "CATHETER": "NO",
    "PRECAUTIONOTHER1": "NO",
    "RECENTEVENTS": "*test\n*newline",
    "PTTIME": "",
    "TYPE": "eval",
    "PATIENTNAME": "Gloria Gordon",
    "CARDIAC": "NO",
    "PRECAUTION": "NO",
    "VISITNUM": "1",
    "PRECAUTIONOTHERNOTE2": " ",
    "SHUNT": "NO",
    "WB": "NO",
    "FALL": "NO",
    "PRECAUTIONOTHER2": "NO",
    "LIVES": " ",
    "THERAPIST": "Bernard George KATZ, PT",
    "PAID": " ",
    "PASTMEDHX": " "
}
```

I need to either remove the /n between *test and *newline or encode it with //n.  I have tried everything I can think of and cannot get the string to replace.

So far I have tried:

- `replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""`
- `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet`

It seems like for some reason, the formmating of the JSON is tripping up the NSString methods.  More likely I am doing something stupid.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you understand the difference between a forward slash and a backslash and that you mean to ask the question the way you did?

Comment: That's a stupid typo.  I am trying to replace \n not /n.

Comment: ... I hope Gloria Gordon is a test person...

Answer (score 0):

`-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` only removes characters at the head and tail of the string it's sent to.  It trims, it doesn't search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, wouldn't the \n refer to the line breaks after each comma?

You may want to replace \\n instead (the literal characters instead of the line breaks)

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure what your problem is but I think you want to take the string: `"*test\n*newline"` and replace it with `"*test\\n*newline"` so that the character `\` will be accepted by a JSON parser?

To do this:

```
NSString *str = @"*test\n*newline";
NSLog(@"First log %@",str);
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
NSLog(@"Second log %@",str);
```

The output from this is as follows

```
First log = *test
*newline 
Second log = *test\n*newline
```

Here you can see that in the first log you have a `\n` which is printed as a new line. In the second log you have a `\\n` which is printed as `\n` as the escape character `\` is escaped and therefore just printed.